# Swift equivalent for while loops with else in python

Tags: swift

I have the following code written in Swift

```
        if current_game_state == game_state.in_game {
            while player_card_values.sum() <= 20 {
                for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                    let point_of_touch = touch.location(in: self)
                    if hit_label.contains(point_of_touch){
                        spawn_card()
                        print("Hit Button Pressed")
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if self.player_card_values.sum() == 21 {
                    print("Player has received BJ!")
                    self.player_status = person_status.stand
                    break
                }
            }
                for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                    let point_of_touch = touch.location(in: self)
                    if stand_label.contains(point_of_touch){
                        print("Stand Button Pressed")
                        player_status = person_status.stand
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

All inside touchesBegan in Spritekit.
But for some reason, I am getting two errors when trying to compile this.

1. Closure expression is unused, on the line where it says else. Not sure why because the expression is not unused, as there is code inside it.
2. Unlabeled break is only allowed inside a loop or a switch, a labeled break is required to exit and if or a do.
   I'm confused here-- what's the difference between an unlabeled and labeled break?
   And the else statement is in response to the while loop, if the sum of the playercardvals is greater than 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `while ... else ...` in Swift, you will have to refactor your logic.

Also, you do not want to loop inside `touchesBegan` your app will stop responding!

Answer (score 0):

**Closure expression is unused, on the line where it says else. Not sure why because the expression is not unused, as there is code inside it.**

> You have `else` right after where your `while` block ends. It makes sense after where `if` / `else if` blocks end, not after `while`.

---

**Unlabeled break is only allowed inside a loop or a switch, a labeled break is required to exit and if or a do.**

> Your `else` block that contains the `break` is not a part of the `while` body.

---

You need to regroup your code, you have misplaced `}` in your code and it is not making sense to the compiler.